# How to solve this word problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

In a box, there are red balls and blue balls.
If one takes away one red ball, then 1/7 of the remaining balls are red.

If one takes away 2 blue balls, then 1/5 of the remaining balls are red.

What is the amount of red and blue balls?

I marked y as red balls and x as blue balls, and we know that x+y is the box, 
then we take away one red ball from the box. but it is unknown, (x+y)-1 red balls = 1/7 red balls + 6/7 blue balls but it doesn't work and i get a decimal. can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Comment: assuming x is blue balls and y is red balsl

Comment: then x+y is the box. I did (x+y) but I am stuck, I don't know how to substract 1 red ball from the box because it is unknown,

Comment: [You can see the answer here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/73MuE.png).

Comment: thank you, I understood pretty much everything, I didn't realize by logic that if the box is x+y, and (x+y-2)*1/5 you get the 1/5 of the box and 1/5 of the box is red., wow, I need to sleep more!!!!!, thank you, I hope I realized there  are many ways to solve this equation, but your way is good too,  1/5 of the remaining box!!!

Comment: @Mork. Ok, nice. Can you please [accept](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6W70.png) my answer then? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ - Number of blue balls
$y$ - Number of red balls

You have two equations:

$$y=\frac15(x+y-2)\\y-1=\frac17(x+y-1)$$

Let $a=x+y$, then by subtracting the second equation from the first one we obtain

$$\frac15(a-2)-\frac17(a-1)=1\\7a-14-5a+5=35\\2a-9=35\\2a=44\\a=22$$

So, the total amount of balls are $22$, now substitute it back:

$$y=\frac15(22-2)=4\\x=22-y=22-4=18$$

The answer is $x=18$ and $y=4$.